# css not working from .css file unless from file itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` on my page that contains breadcrumb with php code, but when I style it with css it doesn't.

I mean if I put styling code in css file & link that file to my `file.php` it doesn't work unless I put styling code on `file.php`.

any solution for this ?

**Code in file.php**

```
<div class="s_crumb">
<?php
    $Pages = array(
      'Clothes' => 'Clothes',
      'file' => 'File'
    );

    $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"http://domain.com\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 2; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> &raquo; ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
<style>
.s_crumb a {color:#848484;text-decoration:none;}
.s_crumb a:visited {color:#848484;text-decoration:none;}
.s_crumb a:hover {color:#bebebe;text-decoration:none;}
</style>
```

Comment: Are you loading your css file in properly in your php file?

Comment: how you are adding css file into this file? tell us. Are you doing something like this:- `<link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: all other divs with styling works the way i linked my css file but only this one doesn't work here is how i linked my css file <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> @Anant

Comment: working fine at my end with your style  code

Comment: @Samir what i think, maybe it's because the page loads php code first then that div can't get styling from css file ?

Comment: This should not be the case @MmPp, Make sure you include your CSS file on your `<head></head>` tag, Which will be present i your main header file.

Comment: @MmPp No, what you think is completely wrong

Comment: you got to be kidding, now it worked :D @Anant i am truly sorry i was trying yesterday what ever i did it didn't work now i think it was that cache problem. thanks again all

Comment: more likely that you have a typo in you css file. From a typo onwards, styles are ignored. e.g. if you don't close a bracket } or have two }} or have a semikolon ; outside {}. I hope you dont use <style> tags within your css file...

Comment: @Toni i have fixed it brother. thanks for your time answering me

Comment: Also: sometimes styles only take effect after a deep refresh of the page (e.g. chrome CTRL + F5, not only F5) since browsers have efficient caching mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:-

Add style like below:-

```
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

***Multiple time due to `cache` css file are not working. So try to remove your `cache` and then check***

Also `css.css` need to be like below:-

```
.s_crumb a {color:#848484;text-decoration:none;}
.s_crumb a:visited {color:#848484;text-decoration:none;}
.s_crumb a:hover {color:#bebebe;text-decoration:none;}
```

remove `<style>` and `</style>` from there

Note:- i tired your code and working fine at my end.